# pyspark high performance rolling/window aggregations on timeseries data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions, rolling-computation

### Basic Question

I have a dataset with ~10 billion rows. I'm looking for the most performant way to calculate rolling/windowed aggregates/metrics (sum, mean, min, max, stddev) over four different time windows (3 days, 7 days, 14 days, 21 days).

### Spark/AWS EMR Specs

spark version: 2.4.4
ec2 instance type: r5.24xlarge
num core ec2 instances: 10
num pyspark partitions: 600

### Overview

I read a bunch of SO posts that addressed either the mechanics of calculating rolling statistics or how to make Window functions faster. However, none of the posts combined these two concepts in a way that solves my problem. I've shown below a few options that do what I want but I need them to operate faster on my real dataset so I'm looking for suggestions that are faster/better.

My dataset is structured as follows but with ~10 billion rows:

```
+--------------------------+----+-----+
|date                      |name|value|
+--------------------------+----+-----+
|2020-12-20 17:45:19.536796|1   |5    |
|2020-12-21 17:45:19.53683 |1   |105  |
|2020-12-22 17:45:19.536846|1   |205  |
|2020-12-23 17:45:19.536861|1   |305  |
|2020-12-24 17:45:19.536875|1   |405  |
|2020-12-25 17:45:19.536891|1   |505  |
|2020-12-26 17:45:19.536906|1   |605  |
|2020-12-20 17:45:19.536796|2   |10   |
|2020-12-21 17:45:19.53683 |2   |110  |
|2020-12-22 17:45:19.536846|2   |210  |
|2020-12-23 17:45:19.536861|2   |310  |
|2020-12-24 17:45:19.536875|2   |410  |
|2020-12-25 17:45:19.536891|2   |510  |
|2020-12-26 17:45:19.536906|2   |610  |
|2020-12-20 17:45:19.536796|3   |15   |
|2020-12-21 17:45:19.53683 |3   |115  |
|2020-12-22 17:45:19.536846|3   |215  |
```

I need my dataset to look like below. Note: window statistics for a 7-day window are shown but I need three other windows as well.

```
+--------------------------+----+-----+----+-----+---+---+------------------+
|date                      |name|value|sum |mean |min|max|stddev            |
+--------------------------+----+-----+----+-----+---+---+------------------+
|2020-12-20 17:45:19.536796|1   |5    |5   |5.0  |5  |5  |NaN               |
|2020-12-21 17:45:19.53683 |1   |105  |110 |55.0 |5  |105|70.71067811865476 |
|2020-12-22 17:45:19.536846|1   |205  |315 |105.0|5  |205|100.0             |
|2020-12-23 17:45:19.536861|1   |305  |620 |155.0|5  |305|129.09944487358058|
|2020-12-24 17:45:19.536875|1   |405  |1025|205.0|5  |405|158.11388300841898|
|2020-12-25 17:45:19.536891|1   |505  |1530|255.0|5  |505|187.08286933869707|
|2020-12-26 17:45:19.536906|1   |605  |2135|305.0|5  |605|216.02468994692867|
|2020-12-20 17:45:19.536796|2   |10   |10  |10.0 |10 |10 |NaN               |
|2020-12-21 17:45:19.53683 |2   |110  |120 |60.0 |10 |110|70.71067811865476 |
|2020-12-22 17:45:19.536846|2   |210  |330 |110.0|10 |210|100.0             |
|2020-12-23 17:45:19.536861|2   |310  |640 |160.0|10 |310|129.09944487358058|
|2020-12-24 17:45:19.536875|2   |410  |1050|210.0|10 |410|158.11388300841898|
|2020-12-25 17:45:19.536891|2   |510  |1560|260.0|10 |510|187.08286933869707|
|2020-12-26 17:45:19.536906|2   |610  |2170|310.0|10 |610|216.02468994692867|
|2020-12-20 17:45:19.536796|3   |15   |15  |15.0 |15 |15 |NaN               |
|2020-12-21 17:45:19.53683 |3   |115  |130 |65.0 |15 |115|70.71067811865476 |
|2020-12-22 17:45:19.536846|3   |215  |345 |115.0|15 |215|100.0             |
```

### Details

For ease of reading, I'll just do one window in these examples. Things I have tried:

1. Basic `Window().over()` syntax
2. Converting windowed values into an array column and using higher order functions
3. Spark SQL

#### Setup

```py
import datetime

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('example').getOrCreate()

# create spark dataframe
n = 7
names = [1, 2, 3]
date_list = [datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=(n-x)) for x in range(n)]
values = [x*100 for x in range(n)]

rows = []
for name in names:
    for d, v in zip(date_list, values):
        rows.append(
            {
                "name": name,
                "date": d,
                "value": v+(5*name)
            }
        )
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=rows)

# setup window
window_days = 7
window = (
    Window
    .partitionBy(F.col("name"))
    .orderBy(F.col("date").cast("timestamp").cast("long"))
    .rangeBetween(-window_days * 60 * 60 * 24 + 1, Window.currentRow)
)
```

#### 1. Basic

This creates multiple window specs as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61706101/how-to-avoid-multiple-window-functions-in-a-expression-in-pyspark) and is therefore performed in serial and runs very slowly on a large dataset

```
status_quo = (df
    .withColumn("sum",F.sum(F.col("value")).over(window))
    .withColumn("mean",F.avg(F.col("value")).over(window))
    .withColumn("min",F.min(F.col("value")).over(window))
    .withColumn("max",F.max(F.col("value")).over(window))
    .withColumn("stddev",F.stddev(F.col("value")).over(window))
)
status_quo.show()
status_quo.explain()
```

#### 2. Array Column --> Higher Order Functions

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61706101/how-to-avoid-multiple-window-functions-in-a-expression-in-pyspark) seems to create fewer window specs, but the `aggregate()` function syntax makes no sense to me, I don't know how to write `stddev` using higher order functions, and the performance doesn't seem much better in small tests

```py
@F.udf(returnType=FloatType())
def array_stddev(row_value):
    """
    temporary function since I don't know how to write higher order standard deviation
    """
    return np.std(row_value, dtype=float).tolist()

# 1. collect window into array column
# 2. use higher order (array) functions to calculate aggregations over array (window values)
# Question: how to write standard deviation in aggregate()
hof_example = (
    df
    .withColumn("value_array", F.collect_list(F.col("value")).over(window))
    .withColumn("sum_example", F.expr('AGGREGATE(value_array, DOUBLE(0), (acc, x) -> acc + x)'))
    .withColumn("mean_example", F.expr('AGGREGATE(value_array, DOUBLE(0), (acc, x) -> acc + x, acc -> acc / size(value_array))'))
    .withColumn("max_example", F.array_max(F.col("value_array")))
    .withColumn("min_example", F.array_min(F.col("value_array")))
    .withColumn("std_example", array_stddev(F.col("value_array")))
)
```

#### 3. Spark SQL

This appears to be the fastest in simple tests. The only (minor) issue is the rest of my codebase uses the DataFrame API. Seems faster in small tests but not tested on full dataset.

```py
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
sql_example = spark.sql(
    """
    SELECT 
        *
        , sum(value)
        OVER (
            PARTITION BY name
            ORDER BY CAST(date AS timestamp) 
            RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 7 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS sum
        , mean(value)
        OVER (
            PARTITION BY name
            ORDER BY CAST(date AS timestamp) 
            RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 7 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS mean
        , min(value)
        OVER (
            PARTITION BY name
            ORDER BY CAST(date AS timestamp) 
            RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 7 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS min
        , max(value)
        OVER (
            PARTITION BY name
            ORDER BY CAST(date AS timestamp) 
            RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 7 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS max
        , stddev(value)
        OVER (
            PARTITION BY name
            ORDER BY CAST(date AS timestamp) 
            RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 7 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS stddev
    FROM df"""
)
```

Comment: Just don't use spark for rolling computations. It's really terrible at that.

Comment: @jangorecki Then what is the recommended approach for the rolling operation?

Comment: data.table or polars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer for the time being. If someone finds a faster/better please notify me and I'll switch it!

EDIT Clarification: The calculations shown here assume input dataframes pre-processed to the day day-level with day-level rolling calculations

After I posted the question I tested several different options on my real dataset (and got some input from coworkers) and I believe the fastest way to do this (for large datasets) uses `pyspark.sql.functions.window()` with `groupby().agg` instead of `pyspark.sql.window.Window()`.

A similar answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49814952/4263486)

The steps to make this work are:

1. sort dataframe by `name` and `date` (in example dataframe)
2. `.persist()` dataframe
3. Compute grouped dataframe using `F.window()` and join back to `df` for every window required.

The best/easiest way to see this in action is on the SQL diagram in the Spark GUI thing. When `Window()` is used, the SQL execution is totally sequential. However, when `F.window()` is used, the diagram shows parallelization! NOTE: on small datasets `Window()` still seems faster.

In my tests with real data on 7-day windows, `Window()` was 3-5x slower than `F.window()`. The only downside is `F.window()` is a bit less convenient to use. I've shown some code and screenshots below for reference

### Fastest Solution Found (`F.window()` with `groupby.agg()`)

```py
# this turned out to be super important for tricking spark into parallelizing things
df = df.orderBy("name", "date")
df.persist()

fwindow7 = F.window(
    F.col("date"),
    windowDuration="7 days",
    slideDuration="1 days",
).alias("window")

gb7 = (
    df
    .groupBy(F.col("name"), fwindow7)
    .agg(
        F.sum(F.col("value")).alias("sum7"),
        F.avg(F.col("value")).alias("mean7"),
        F.min(F.col("value")).alias("min7"),
        F.max(F.col("value")).alias("max7"),
        F.stddev(F.col("value")).alias("stddev7"),
        F.count(F.col("value")).alias("cnt7")
    )
    .withColumn("date", F.date_sub(F.col("window.end").cast("date"), 1))
    .drop("window")
)
window_function_example = df.join(gb7, ["name", "date"], how="left")


fwindow14 = F.window(
    F.col("date"),
    windowDuration="14 days",
    slideDuration="1 days",
).alias("window")

gb14 = (
    df
    .groupBy(F.col("name"), fwindow14)
    .agg(
        F.sum(F.col("value")).alias("sum14"),
        F.avg(F.col("value")).alias("mean14"),
        F.min(F.col("value")).alias("min14"),
        F.max(F.col("value")).alias("max14"),
        F.stddev(F.col("value")).alias("stddev14"),
        F.count(F.col("value")).alias("cnt14")
    )
    .withColumn("date", F.date_sub(F.col("window.end").cast("date"), 1))
    .drop("window")
)
window_function_example = window_function_example.join(gb14, ["name", "date"], how="left")
window_function_example.orderBy("name", "date").show(truncate=True)
```

SQL Diagram

[image: Group By]

### Option 2 from Original Question (Higher Order Functions applied to `Window()`)

```py
window7 = (
    Window
    .partitionBy(F.col("name"))
    .orderBy(F.col("date").cast("timestamp").cast("long"))
    .rangeBetween(-7 * 60 * 60 * 24 + 1, Window.currentRow)
)
window14 = (
    Window
    .partitionBy(F.col("name"))
    .orderBy(F.col("date").cast("timestamp").cast("long"))
    .rangeBetween(-14 * 60 * 60 * 24 + 1, Window.currentRow)
)
hof_example = (
    df
    .withColumn("value_array", F.collect_list(F.col("value")).over(window7))
    .withColumn("sum7", F.expr('AGGREGATE(value_array, DOUBLE(0), (acc, x) -> acc + x)'))
    .withColumn("mean7", F.expr('AGGREGATE(value_array, DOUBLE(0), (acc, x) -> acc + x, acc -> acc / size(value_array))'))
    .withColumn("max7", F.array_max(F.col("value_array")))
    .withColumn("min7", F.array_min(F.col("value_array")))
    .withColumn("std7", F.expr('AGGREGATE(value_array, DOUBLE(0), (acc, x) -> acc + (x - mean7)*(x - mean7), acc -> sqrt(acc / (size(value_array) - 1)))'))
    .withColumn("count7", F.size(F.col("value_array")))
    .drop("value_array")
)
hof_example = (
    hof_example
    .withColumn("value_array", F.collect_list(F.col("value")).over(window14))
    .withColumn("sum14", F.expr('AGGREGATE(value_array, DOUBLE(0), (acc, x) -> acc + x)'))
    .withColumn("mean14", F.expr('AGGREGATE(value_array, DOUBLE(0), (acc, x) -> acc + x, acc -> acc / size(value_array))'))
    .withColumn("max14", F.array_max(F.col("value_array")))
    .withColumn("min14", F.array_min(F.col("value_array")))
    .withColumn("std14", F.expr('AGGREGATE(value_array, DOUBLE(0), (acc, x) -> acc + (x - mean14)*(x - mean14), acc -> sqrt(acc / (size(value_array) - 1)))'))
    .withColumn("count14", F.size(F.col("value_array")))
    .drop("value_array")
)

hof_example.show(truncate=True)
```

SQL Diagram Snippet

[image: Higher Order Functions]

Comment: your option-1 does NOT do the same thing as option-2. your option-1 rounded up the calculation to the day-level, and if there are multiple rows for the same date, the result will be the same for them while option-2 will yield different result. even if the dates are in 7-days, the records might not be included in the same window for option-2 since the hour/min/sec might be out of boundary. option-2 can be improved if you are looking for a slide window in sub second-level which option-1 fail to work.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I will edit the answer to clarify that this is for daily averages using a pre-processed dataframe

Answer (score 2):

Try this aggregate for stddev. If you want to understand the syntax, you can check the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#aggregate).

```
hof_example = (
    df
    .withColumn("value_array", F.collect_list(F.col("value")).over(window))
    .withColumn("sum_example", F.expr('AGGREGATE(value_array, DOUBLE(0), (acc, x) -> acc + x)'))
    .withColumn("mean_example", F.expr('AGGREGATE(value_array, DOUBLE(0), (acc, x) -> acc + x, acc -> acc / size(value_array))'))
    .withColumn("max_example", F.array_max(F.col("value_array")))
    .withColumn("min_example", F.array_min(F.col("value_array")))
    .withColumn("std_example", F.expr('AGGREGATE(value_array, DOUBLE(0), (acc, x) -> acc + (x - mean_example)*(x - mean_example), acc -> sqrt(acc / (size(value_array) - 1)))'))
)
```

By the way, I don't think the other two approaches (pyspark window vs spark sql) are different. The query plans look identical to me. (I only selected min and max to reduce the size of the query plan)

Pyspark query plan:

```
status_quo = (df
    .withColumn("min",F.min(F.col("value")).over(window))
    .withColumn("max",F.max(F.col("value")).over(window))
)
status_quo.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
*(4) Project [date#3793, name#3794L, value#3795L, min#3800L, max#3807L]
+- Window [max(value#3795L) windowspecdefinition(name#3794L, _w0#3808L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, -604799, currentrow$())) AS max#3807L], [name#3794L], [_w0#3808L ASC NULLS FIRST]
   +- *(3) Sort [name#3794L ASC NULLS FIRST, _w0#3808L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- *(3) Project [date#3793, name#3794L, value#3795L, min#3800L, cast(date#3793 as bigint) AS _w0#3808L]
         +- Window [min(value#3795L) windowspecdefinition(name#3794L, _w0#3801L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, -604799, currentrow$())) AS min#3800L], [name#3794L], [_w0#3801L ASC NULLS FIRST]
            +- *(2) Sort [name#3794L ASC NULLS FIRST, _w0#3801L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
               +- Exchange hashpartitioning(name#3794L, 200), true, [id=#812]
                  +- *(1) Project [date#3793, name#3794L, value#3795L, cast(date#3793 as bigint) AS _w0#3801L]
                     +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[date#3793,name#3794L,value#3795L]
```

Spark SQL query plan:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
sql_example = spark.sql(
    """
    SELECT 
        *
        , min(value)
        OVER (
            PARTITION BY name
            ORDER BY CAST(date AS timestamp) 
            RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 7 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS min
        , max(value)
        OVER (
            PARTITION BY name
            ORDER BY CAST(date AS timestamp) 
            RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 7 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS max
    FROM df"""
)
sql_example.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
*(4) Project [date#3793, name#3794L, value#3795L, min#4670L, max#4671L]
+- Window [max(value#3795L) windowspecdefinition(name#3794L, _w1#4675 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, -7 days, currentrow$())) AS max#4671L], [name#3794L], [_w1#4675 ASC NULLS FIRST]
   +- *(3) Sort [name#3794L ASC NULLS FIRST, _w1#4675 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- *(3) Project [date#3793, name#3794L, value#3795L, _w1#4675, min#4670L]
         +- Window [min(value#3795L) windowspecdefinition(name#3794L, _w0#4674 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, -7 days, currentrow$())) AS min#4670L], [name#3794L], [_w0#4674 ASC NULLS FIRST]
            +- *(2) Sort [name#3794L ASC NULLS FIRST, _w0#4674 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
               +- Exchange hashpartitioning(name#3794L, 200), true, [id=#955]
                  +- *(1) Project [date#3793, name#3794L, value#3795L, date#3793 AS _w0#4674, date#3793 AS _w1#4675]
                     +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[date#3793,name#3794L,value#3795L]
```

Aggregate function query plan:

```
hof_example.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
Project [date#3793, name#3794L, value#3795L, value_array#5516, aggregate(value_array#5516, 0.0, lambdafunction((lambda acc#5523 + cast(lambda x#5524L as double)), lambda acc#5523, lambda x#5524L, false), lambdafunction(lambda id#5525, lambda id#5525, false)) AS sum_example#5522, aggregate(value_array#5516, 0.0, lambdafunction((lambda acc#5532 + cast(lambda x#5533L as double)), lambda acc#5532, lambda x#5533L, false), lambdafunction((lambda acc#5534 / cast(size(value_array#5516, true) as double)), lambda acc#5534, false)) AS mean_example#5531, array_max(value_array#5516) AS max_example#5541L, array_min(value_array#5516) AS min_example#5549L, aggregate(value_array#5516, 0.0, lambdafunction((lambda acc#5559 + ((cast(lambda x#5560L as double) - aggregate(value_array#5516, 0.0, lambdafunction((lambda acc#5532 + cast(lambda x#5533L as double)), lambda acc#5532, lambda x#5533L, false), lambdafunction((lambda acc#5534 / cast(size(value_array#5516, true) as double)), lambda acc#5534, false))) * (cast(lambda x#5560L as double) - aggregate(value_array#5516, 0.0, lambdafunction((lambda acc#5532 + cast(lambda x#5533L as double)), lambda acc#5532, lambda x#5533L, false), lambdafunction((lambda acc#5534 / cast(size(value_array#5516, true) as double)), lambda acc#5534, false))))), lambda acc#5559, lambda x#5560L, false), lambdafunction(SQRT((lambda acc#5561 / cast((size(value_array#5516, true) - 1) as double))), lambda acc#5561, false)) AS std_example#5558]
+- Window [collect_list(value#3795L, 0, 0) windowspecdefinition(name#3794L, _w0#5517L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, -604799, currentrow$())) AS value_array#5516], [name#3794L], [_w0#5517L ASC NULLS FIRST]
   +- *(2) Sort [name#3794L ASC NULLS FIRST, _w0#5517L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(name#3794L, 200), true, [id=#1136]
         +- *(1) Project [date#3793, name#3794L, value#3795L, cast(date#3793 as bigint) AS _w0#5517L]
            +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[date#3793,name#3794L,value#3795L]
```