# PySpark windowing over datetimes and including windows containing no rows in the results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to aggregate my data by getting the sum every 30 seconds. I would like to know if the result of this aggregation is zero, this will happen if there are no rows in that 30s region.

Here's a minimal working example illustrating the result I would like with pandas, and where it falls short with pyspark.

## Input data

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        (17, "2017-03-10T15:27:18+00:00"),
        (13, "2017-03-10T15:27:29+00:00"),
        (25, "2017-03-10T15:27:30+00:00"),
        (101, "2017-03-10T15:29:00+00:00"),
        (99, "2017-03-10T15:29:29+00:00")
    ],
    columns=["dollars", "timestamp"],
)
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
print(df)
```

```
    dollars timestamp
0   17  2017-03-10 15:27:18+00:00
1   13  2017-03-10 15:27:29+00:00
2   25  2017-03-10 15:27:30+00:00
3   101 2017-03-10 15:29:00+00:00
4   99  2017-03-10 15:29:29+00:00
```

## Pandas solution

With pandas, we can use resample to aggregate every 30 second window, and then apply the sum function over these windows (note the results for `2017-03-10 15:28:00+00:00`, and `2017-03-10 15:28:30+00:00`):

```py
desired_result = df.set_index("timestamp").resample("30S").sum()
desired_result
```

```
                            dollars
timestamp   
2017-03-10 15:27:00+00:00   30
2017-03-10 15:27:30+00:00   25
2017-03-10 15:28:00+00:00   0
2017-03-10 15:28:30+00:00   0
2017-03-10 15:29:00+00:00   200
```

## PySpark near solution

In pyspark, we can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.window`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.window.html) to window over every 30 seconds (adapted, with thanks from [this stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65839905/2550114)), but this will miss out the window where there are no rows:

```py
spark: pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession  # I expect you to have set up your session...
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)
sdf.groupby(
    F.window("timestamp", windowDuration="30 seconds", slideDuration="30 seconds")
).agg(F.sum("dollars")).display()
```

```
window,sum(dollars)
"{""start"":""2017-03-10T15:27:30.000+0000"",""end"":""2017-03-10T15:28:00.000+0000""}",25
"{""start"":""2017-03-10T15:27:00.000+0000"",""end"":""2017-03-10T15:27:30.000+0000""}",30
"{""start"":""2017-03-10T15:29:00.000+0000"",""end"":""2017-03-10T15:29:30.000+0000""}",200
```

## Question

How do I get pyspark to return window results for time window where there are no rows (like pandas)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use timestamp arithmetic [as mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39810441/8761414) (I recommend you take a look at it as he goes into details). In your case it would be:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

seconds = 30
epoch = (F.col("timestamp").cast("timestamp").cast("bigint") / seconds).cast(
    "bigint"
) * seconds
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (17, "2017-03-10T15:27:18+00:00"),
        (13, "2017-03-10T15:27:29+00:00"),
        (25, "2017-03-10T15:27:30+00:00"),
        (101, "2017-03-10T15:29:00+00:00"),
        (99, "2017-03-10T15:29:29+00:00"),
    ],
    ["dollars", "timestamp"],
).withColumn("epoch", epoch)

min_epoch, max_epoch = df.select(F.min("epoch"), F.max("epoch")).first()

ref = spark.range(min_epoch, max_epoch + seconds, seconds).toDF("epoch")

(
    ref.join(df, "epoch", "left")
    .withColumn("ts_resampled", F.timestamp_seconds("epoch"))
    .groupBy("ts_resampled")
    .sum("dollars")
    .orderBy("ts_resampled")
    .fillna(0, subset=["sum(dollars)"])
    .show(truncate=False)
)
```

**Output**

```
|ts_resampled       |sum(dollars)|
+-------------------+------------+
|2017-03-10 12:27:00|30          |
|2017-03-10 12:27:30|25          |
|2017-03-10 12:28:00|0           |
|2017-03-10 12:28:30|0           |
|2017-03-10 12:29:00|200         |
+-------------------+------------+
```

Comment: FYI, `timestamp_seconds` is spark 3.1.0+

Answer (score 3):

Same solution than Ottovon but in Spark2.4 and without the action `first`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

seconds = 30
epoch = (F.col("timestamp").cast("timestamp").cast("bigint") / seconds).cast(
    "bigint"
) * seconds
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (17, "2017-03-10T15:27:18+00:00"),
        (13, "2017-03-10T15:27:29+00:00"),
        (25, "2017-03-10T15:27:30+00:00"),
        (101, "2017-03-10T15:29:00+00:00"),
        (99, "2017-03-10T15:29:29+00:00"),
    ],
    ["dollars", "timestamp"],
).withColumn("epoch", epoch)

ref = df.select(
    F.min("epoch").alias("min_epoch"), F.max("epoch").alias("max_epoch")
).select(
    F.explode(F.sequence("min_epoch", "max_epoch", F.lit(seconds))).alias("epoch")
)

ref.show()
+----------+                                                                    
|     epoch|
+----------+
|1489159620|
|1489159650|
|1489159680|
|1489159710|
|1489159740|
+----------+
```

```py
resampled_df = (
    ref.join(df, "epoch", "left")
    .withColumn("ts_resampled", F.from_unixtime("epoch"))
    .groupBy("ts_resampled")
    .agg(F.coalesce(F.sum("dollars"), F.lit(0)).alias("dollars"))
    .orderBy("ts_resampled")
)

resampled_df.show()
+-------------------+-------+                                                   
|       ts_resampled|dollars|
+-------------------+-------+
|2017-03-10 15:27:00|     30|
|2017-03-10 15:27:30|     25|
|2017-03-10 15:28:00|      0|
|2017-03-10 15:28:30|      0|
|2017-03-10 15:29:00|    200|
+-------------------+-------+
```

Comment: In epoch you are only transforming the date to epoch no? I tried with a column of only date and seems it doesn't work very well, I think it is better to use `epoch = F.unix_timestamp(F.col('date'),"yyyy-MM-dd")` and that way is more understandable, and you can define how is the format.